# Query pagination using minTimeuuid and maxTimeuuid

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-2.0

I have a cassandra table with a Timeuuid primary key and I would like to process the whole table in chunks on various processing nodes.

So, I thought I could chunk the processing using minTimeuuid/maxTimeuuid:

- To start their jobs, each node would get a time range they should acquire from Cassandra, query for it and process it.
- The data density is fairly uniform, so there shouldn't be any issue there.

What trips me is if I were to do this:

```
   SELECT * FROM myTable
   WHERE t > maxTimeuuid('2013-01-01 00:05+0000')
   AND t < minTimeuuid('2013-02-02 10:00+0000')
```

The documentation says:

> The min/maxTimeuuid example selects all rows where the timeuuid
>   column, t, is strictly later than 2013-01-01 00:05+0000 but strictly
>   earlier than 2013-02-02 10:00+0000. The t >= maxTimeuuid('2013-01-01
>   00:05+0000') does not select a timeuuid generated exactly at
>   2013-01-01 00:05+0000 and is essentially equivalent to t >
>   maxTimeuuid('2013-01-01 00:05+0000').

So from what I understand, if I were to select a range starting from '2013-02-02 10:00+0000' for the next chunk, I would miss data that's exactly at that time because none of them covers that exact date.

Ok, I understand that because of the way a Timeuuid is generated this is unlikely but I still feel uncomfortable about the possibility of dropping some results. There's the possibility of checking for duplicates afterward but that's a fairly expensive operation on a cluster.

**EDIT:**

Ok, so apparently I can't do range queries on a Timeuuid. As asked, here's my table:

```
CREATE TABLE cgr.reports (
    pk_1 text,
    pk_2 text,
    pk_3 bigint,
    pk_4 bigint,
    some_data text,
    PRIMARY KEY ((pk_1, pk_2, pk_3, pk_4))
);
```

The PK don't really need to be an aggregate of those 4 because I realized at some point that no query is planned on those. That's when I thought I could do the range query on a Timeuuid, so I thought I could do this instead:

```
CREATE TABLE cgr.reports (
    pk_uuid Timeuuid,
    data_1 text,
    data_2 text,
    data_3 bigint,
    data_4 bigint,
    some_data text,
    PRIMARY KEY ((pk_uuid))
);
```

What I really want to do is split the processing between various nodes. I guess a way to do is to query all the row id and send chunks of them to the various nodes. I know that's going to work with the current volume I have, I'm just worried about later when it grows.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Can you post your table definition?  Also, you can't range query on a partition key, so you'll need to have a partition key, and then a clustering key to query your range on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
CREATE TABLE cgr.reports (
    timebucket int,
    pk_uuid Timeuuid,
    data_1 text,
    data_2 text,
    data_3 bigint,
    data_4 bigint,
    some_data text,
    PRIMARY KEY (timebucket, pk_uuid)
);
```

Where **timebucket** is **pk_uuid** modulo **some_number**. **some_number** should be high enough to split the data equally to your nodes and low enough to aggregate some volume of the data for your workers, to not query frequently for many small chunks. Each worker would have assigned reminder of division and processes those values only.

However, the perfect way would be like this:

```
CREATE TABLE cgr.reports (
    pk_uuid Timeuuid,
    data_1 text,
    data_2 text,
    data_3 bigint,
    data_4 bigint,
    some_data text,
    PRIMARY KEY (data_1, pk_uuid)
);
```

Where data_1 has high cardinality and is known for your workers. This splits data equally to your clusters and time range queries are allowed on pk_uuid. Each worker has assigned data_1 values and processes those values only.

**Edit:**
**Timeuuid selects explanation:**

I haven't tested that, however my understanding is as follows:

Timeuuid is basically Time+UUID. Therefore if you can ask Cassandra only queries:

```
t > minTimeuuid(x) AND t < maxTimeuuid(y)
```

where x < y, you will select time in range (x_000, y_999) - _abc is the clockid + nodeid.

But what's after y_999? It's (y+1 tick)_000 - it's minTimeuuid(y+1). Therefore executing query:

```
t > minTimeuuid(x) AND t < minTimeuuid(y+1)
```

you will select time in range (x_000, y+1_000). You won't select y+1_000 or y+1_389, but you will select y_999.

Next query, adjacent to this will be:

```
t > maxTimeuuid(y) AND t < minTimeuuid(z+1)
```

time range here is (y_999, z+1_000). Therefore you won't select y_999.

However, be warned that this is just my understanding and please let me know after you test it if this works. What is more, depending on you driver, this may vary, as C# driver implementation shown: http://nickberardi.com/sometimes-a-nanosecond-makes-all-the-difference/

Comment: I understand what you're saying, it's a good idea to split the work like that.

The only part I'm not clear on, is how the range queries work since the boundaries are non inclusives. As I understand it, if a window upper range is "2013-02-02 10:00+0000" and the next one lower boundary is the same ( "2013-02-02 10:00+0000" ) there would be a small crack where rows could slip into in theory.

Comment: @CodeHerder I've updated my answer. However it's theory so please test it and let me know if it works.